# How to Loop Through Multiple Calendars to Find Times Everyone is Available

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have the following google app script that loops through my calendar for the next two weeks and finds any open time slots at least 30 mins long between 9am and 6pm Mo-Fri excluding the hour of 12pm-1pm for lunch each day. It then emails me a table with all of the time slots.

I would like to modify it so I can add in other co-workers calendar IDs and find times available to both of us or potentially more people? I am assuming I would just need an array of all the calendar IDs I want to use but I am unsure of how to actually implement that. Any ideas are appreciated!

```
function findAvailableTimeSlotsAndEmail() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var startDate = new Date();
  var endDate = new Date();
  endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 14);
  var events = calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate);
  var availableSlots = [];
  var currentSlot = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
    if (date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6) {
      // Skip weekends
      continue;
    }
    for (var j = 9; j <= 17; j++) {
      if (j == 12) {
        // Skip lunch hour
        continue;
      }
      for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        var minutes = k * 30;
        var startTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), j, minutes);
        var endTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), j, minutes + 30);
        var hasEvent = false;
        for (var l = 0; l < events.length; l++) {
          var event = events[l];
          if (event.getStartTime() < endTime && event.getEndTime() > startTime) {
            hasEvent = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!hasEvent) {
          if (currentSlot == null) {
            currentSlot = [date, startTime, endTime];
          } else {
            if (currentSlot[0].getTime() == date.getTime() && currentSlot[2].getTime() == startTime.getTime()) {
              // extend the current slot if it's consecutive
              currentSlot[2] = endTime;
            } else {
              // otherwise, add the current slot to the list of available slots and start a new slot
              availableSlots.push(currentSlot);
              currentSlot = [date, startTime, endTime];
            }
          }
        } else {
          // if the current slot is not available, add it to the list of available slots (if it exists) and reset the current slot
          if (currentSlot != null) {
            availableSlots.push(currentSlot);
            currentSlot = null;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // add the final current slot to the list of available slots
    if (currentSlot != null) {
      availableSlots.push(currentSlot);
      currentSlot = null;
    }
  }

  if (availableSlots.length > 0) {
    // Generate the HTML table for the available time slots
    var html = "<table><tr><th>Date</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Duration</th></tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < availableSlots.length; i++) {
      var slot = availableSlots[i];
      var start = slot[1];
      var end = slot[2];
      var duration = (end - start) / 3600000;
      var formattedDuration = (duration === 1) ? "1 hour" : (duration + " hours");
      html += "<tr><td>" + slot[0].toDateString() + "</td><td>" + start.toLocaleTimeString() + "</td><td>" + end.toLocaleTimeString() + "</td><td>" + formattedDuration + "</td></tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";

    // Send an email with the available time slots table
    var recipient = "example@email.com";
    var subject = "Upcoming Availability";
    var body = "My Availability is below in EST:<br><br>" + html;
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "", {htmlBody: body});
  }
}
```

Comment: ['id1','id2','id3'].forEach(id => { let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id)})

Comment: @Brendon I understand that you want to go through multiple calendars and see the open time slots, is that correct? Like mentioned in the previous comment, adding that line to your script will go through all calendars specified and send you a separate email with each calendar open time slots.